# Plot correlation matrix (pdf) in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, matrices

Ok, giving up...

I need to plot a correlation matrix exactly shown in the attached picture. I have 15 images in a PDF form, but the issue is that to plot these images on diagonal in LaTeX. I need to use LaTeX and only LaTeX. I do know how to plot using other programs tho. Any suggestions?

[image]

UPDATE:

thanks for the suggestions. I just wonder is there a way to crop and clip the images because my attempt to plot the correlation matrix worked, but now I have a huge gap between the figures and the numbers and labels are too small. This is what I have tried to do:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
   \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 4cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
     \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}\\
&  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}\\
&&  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}\\
&&&  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}\\
&&&&  \includegraphics[trim=3cm 7cm 0cm 5cm,clip=true, totalheight=0.1\textheight]{fig/histplt_2.pdf}
\end{tabular}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tabular` seems to be the easiest way. Proper dimensions are left to you.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
     \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}\\
&  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}\\
&&  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}\\
&&&  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}&
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}\\
&&&&  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps using a macro wrapper for `\includegraphics` with this settings would make the code a little bit more concise

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Generally: of course. However in this case I am not sure if OP knows something about macros.

Comment: I see this might be an issue!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Is there a way to crop and clip automatically? When I tried to plot the correlation matrix there is a huge gap between the plots/figures. These are my attempt to fix the gap between the plots, but did not help me much. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: @Sally7874: Yes. `texdoc grfguide`.

Comment: @Martin Schröder, where to employ this function? Thanks